# Best practice column wrapping Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, grid

According to this [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#column-wrapping), you can use column wrapping with bootstrap.

Here a part of my code:

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="col-7">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            3
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            4
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            5
        </div>
    </div>
```

It works, but is it the best solution? Or is it necessary to create a row each time, which would give:

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-7">
            2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            4
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            5
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**No, you no longer need rows.** From the Bootstrap 5.0 documentation:

The .col-* classes can also be used outside a .row to give an element a specific width. Whenever column classes are used as non direct children of a row, the paddings are omitted.

So you can use your first method.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap rows are set to wrap by default. So if two columns' width sum up greater than 12, the 2nd one will be wrapped into new line:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9">
            .col-9
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            .col-4
        <!-- Since 9 + 4 = 13 > 12, this 4-column-wide div gets wrapped 
             onto a new line as one contiguous unit. -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            .col-6
        <!-- Subsequent columns continue along the new line. -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If the default behavior serves you well, you don't have to put new rows each time.

The only time you would need new rows is when your intend to make them new rows:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">2</div>
        <div class="col-3">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I don't put a new row for column #2 and #3, column #2 will be on the same row of column #1, by default.

To me, I prefer the 2nd way because that shows my intention of wanting columns to be in new rows. Others don't have to guess or know Bootstrap default behavior.